# Content browser shows files that was deleted on disk

Tags: unreal-engine4

I imported into the project a package that includes blueprints and c++ classes. Then I closed the editor, removed all this content from the disk, including c++.
After running unreal, C++ classes that I removed from the disk remained in the content browser, but they cannot be opened.

Why is this happening? How to delete them? Where does the content browser get information from? Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes visible in the content browsers are classes that were compiled and loaded by the editor. If you recompile and reload the editor they should disappear.